# What happens if you apply "gradient descent" to the complex derivative?

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

In gradient descent you have a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. You choose an initial point $x_0$, and set $$x_{i+1} = x_i - \gamma f'(x_i)$$ Repeating this with small enough step size $\gamma$ tends to lead you to a local minimum of $f$.

Suppose you do the same thing with a complex holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. You choose an initial point $z_0$ and set $z_{i+1} = z_i - \gamma f'(z_i)$. Does repeating this with small enough $\gamma$ tend to lead you towards or around any interesting features of $f$?

Comment: As $\gamma \rightarrow 0$, the iterates should converge to the solution of the ODE $\dot{z}(t)=-f'(z(t))$.

Comment: @p.s. Sure, and do solutions of that ODE lead towards or around interesting features of f?

Comment: @causative Why don't you pick a simple toy $f$ and give it a try?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have tried plotting f' as a vector field on top of representations of f. If the result is meaningful I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: It would perhaps be more interesting if you used the actual gradient, which is the Hermitean adjoint of the derivative, here $\overline{f'(z)}$. Remember the general definition of the gradient is $Df(x)[v]=\langle\nabla f(x),v\rangle$, left the directional derivative, right the scalar product, with the first operand anti-linear.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see, so following the conjugate derivative takes us in the direction of increasing real part of f.

Comment: Or decreasing, in the case of the gradient _descent_, see the minus sign. Due to the open mapping property of holomorphic functions there is no lower bound, so one can expect a quite vigorous escape to infinity.